# Wordpress Function Within a Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

In brief, I am trying to effectively insert a PHP function into the shortcode and having no luck.

**The shortcode:**

```
[res_map address=""]
```

**The function:**

```
<?php the_field('address'); ?>
```

**What I have so far:**

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[res_map address="' . the_field("address") . '"]'); ?>
```

Any help on how to properly do this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The argument `content` has to be a string to search for `shortcodes` , what your `the_field` function returns ?

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
$ret = the_field("address");
echo do_shortcode('[res_map address = "'. $ret .'"]');
```

In this case, your function must return a string, i.e.

```
function the_field($arg)
{
    // ... 
    return 'something';
}
```

Because [do_shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function expects `string` as it's argument and it's required. For example, it should be something like this

```
echo do_shortcode('[res_map address = "something"]');
```